# Is a PHP file secure enough on a GoDaddy Server to hard code an AES salt into the file?

Tags: php, security, web-services, api-design, encryption

So I am creating a web api for an app I am making. The data is sanitized before it is sent to my web api and then encrypted before it is stored in my MySql server.

The phone app sanitizes then behind the scenes calls -> web php api which encrypts aes style with a hard coded salt then calls -> server

My question is if I hard code a salt value into the php page is it at risk on a go daddy server?

I mean I know NOTHING is truly secure however what are the odds that someone would be able to hack a go daddy server and see my php source code. Assuming they disassemble my app and see the URL call to the api.

Since php code executes on the server I am assuming that there is no way to extract it?

Comment: Perhaps better asked at the [security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) site? (btw please don't re-post, but flag for moderator attention to have your question migrated).

Comment: Given GoDaddy's security record plus using PHP means pushing the source code to the server means Security.SE's will advocate better key management practices will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just wanted to follow up on this question now that I'm a little more seasoned as an engineer.

One work around to this I've found is putting sensitive information, api keys, salts, etc etc into json config files that are outside the scope of the webserver. I usually stick it under `/var/securelocation/websiteconfig.json`. Then when I write a php script I load that json config file into a php object and I access the properties I need.

This method is nice because it not only reduces the chance you'll leak your sensitive info if there's a problem with your php or webserver but it also makes it very easy to upload your code to GitHub without having to sanitize it. Just provide an example json file for the next user and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is very common practice to put constants (passwords, salts etc.) in php files.

How could you store your salt else? In a database? Where do you put your database credentials - again in the source code.
You can also store it in an include file (.inc) and use that in your php code. It does not matter very much.

Speaking of GoDaddy: I have no clue if that hoster is more secure than another hoster, but technically it is all the same.

Comment: Re security: GoDaddy have had major hacking related breaches in [2010](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/05/09/mass-shared-host-website-hack/) and [2011](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/19/go_daddy_mass_compromise/) plus outages in [2012](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/blog/2012/sep/10/godaddy-hacked-domain-registrar-anonymous) and [earlier this year](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/03/13/godaddy_ddos_attack_european_servers/).

Comment: @JamesSnell Oh I know ALLLLLL about the outages..... That's how I got half off on my current delux hosting plan lol. So irritatating.

Comment: @TMS Thank you so much for the clear answer. My gut told me it was secure since it only returns text and no php source. Thought I would ask though.

Comment: @AMR There is the possiblity to return the code of a script, but that needs more than just HTTP/GET access - which must be enabled on the server itself: and if you can do that, you can also just 'view' the source on the server. Otherwise the script will always return the output (the html) or an errormessage.

Comment: @TMS That is exactly what I am worried about. What is the call that pulls an php script?

Comment: @AMR I could not find it right now, but I think it was an some kind of plungin or extension for the webserver/apache. It can't be done client-side only. See also on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563438/can-a-client-view-server-side-php-source-code)